# Next.js fetch with Suspense

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, react-suspense

According to the docs, this is a typical `fetch` with `Suspense` pattern (a bit simplified).-

```
import { getArtist, getArtistAlbums, type Album } from './api';
 
export default async function Page({
  params: { username },
}: {
  params: { username: string };
}) {
  const albumData = getArtistAlbums(username);
 
 
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Albums promise={albumData} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
 
// Albums Component
async function Albums({ promise }: { promise: Promise<Album[]> }) {
  // Wait for the albums promise to resolve
  const albums = await promise;
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {albums.map((album) => (
        <li key={album.id}>{album.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

It actually works fine, but `Visual Studio Code` keeps complaining on

`<Albums promise={albumData} />`

due to

`Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.`

**Am I missing something obvious here? Is this a `Lint` error that I can somehow silence? Or maybe a versions issue?** Any tip on the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this not mentioned in the docs here? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components

Comment: OMG I was pretty sure I read something like it but was totally unable to find it. Thank so much @StuartNichols, and please feel free to post the answer :)

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer to complete the question.

Comment: Latest typescript fixes this.

Comment: Thank you @Micael, just updated to 5.1.3 but still seeing the issue, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NextJS documentation states that this is a known TypeScript error that is being worked on. From the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components):

> Async Server Component TypeScript Error
>
> An async Server Components will cause a 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element type error where it is used.
> This is a known issue with TypeScript and is being worked on upstream.
> As a temporary workaround, you can add {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */} above the component to disable type checking for it.